# How fast is querying threadIdx, blockIdx, blockDim?

Tags: cuda

This is a rather straight forward question. How fast is reading the `threadIdx`, `blockIdx` and `blockDim`
variable? For example, if I need them a few times within my kernel, should I write them to a local register first, or does it not matter if I just access them directly?

So, in essence, I'm asking in which memory of the following illustration do `threadIdx`, `blockIdx` and `blockDim` live:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "should I write them to a local register first"? Are you writing your own PTX code?

Comment: @talonmies I mean within my kernel, should I write `uint myIdx= threadIdx.x` for example, if I need the value several times. As far as I understand it, `myIdx` in this case would be saved in local registers, which is very fast memory.

Comment: I understand you are asking about kernels, but unless you are writing assembly by hand, you have no control over what the compiler does or does not put in registers and no control (or idea) whether directly accessing a special variable will result in the compiler automatically loading a special variable to a register and reusing that register multiple times. The entire premise of your question is based on several assumptions that are either irrelevant or untrue

Comment: Can it be, that we are speaking of different things? I have editd the OP to hopefully illustrate my question better.

Comment: All those dimensions variables map to special registers. Performance differences are related to latency, not throughout. Take 5 minutes to read the first few pages of the PTX guide

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @talonmies mentioned it is not predictable how exactly the compiler treats variables. Nonetheless, I developed a simple test on my system (Windows 10, CUDA 10.2, Tesla k40) to analyze the compiler's behavior in my case regarding your question. Let's `#define nTPB 1024` as the number of threads per block. `kernel_1` is storing `threadId.x` in `t` located in the registers and reads `t` multiple time whereas in `kernel_2`, `threadId.x` is used directly every time.

```
// kernel_1 stores threadId.x in t
__global__ void kernel_1(const int N, const int offset, const unsigned *v, unsigned *o) 
{
    unsigned n_ept = (unsigned)(ceil)((double)N / nTPB); // No of elements per thread
    unsigned t = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned t_min = t * n_ept;
    unsigned t_max = (t+1) * n_ept;
    for (unsigned i = t_min; i < t_max; i++) {
        if( i < N)
            o[i] = v[i + offset] + t + t / 2;
    }
}

// kernel_2 does not stores threadId.x
__global__ void kernel_2(const int N, const int offset, const unsigned *v, unsigned *o)
{
    unsigned n_ept = (unsigned)(ceil)((double)N / nTPB); // No of elements per thread
    unsigned t_min = threadIdx.x * n_ept;
    unsigned t_max = (threadIdx.x + 1) * n_ept;
    for (unsigned i = t_min; i < t_max; i++) {
        if (i < N)
            o[i] = v[i + offset] + threadIdx.x + threadIdx.x / 2;
    }
}
```

Calling each function 100 times in the following manner, I measured the performance of each kernel:

```
int main()
{

    int N = 100000;
    int offset = 4;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point cpu_startTime;

    unsigned *h_v = new unsigned[N+offset];
    for (int i = 0; i < N+offset; i++)
        h_v[i] = 10;
    unsigned *d_v;
    unsigned *d_o;
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_v, (N+offset) * sizeof(unsigned)));
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(d_v, h_v, (N+offset) * sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_o, N * sizeof(unsigned)));

    dim3 threads(nTPB);

    cpu_startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        kernel_1 <<<1, threads >>> (N, offset, d_v, d_o);
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_data_1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - cpu_startTime;

    cpu_startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        kernel_2 <<<1, threads >>> (N, offset, d_v, d_o);
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_data_2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - cpu_startTime;

    double elapsed_1 = 1000 * elapsed_data_1.count(); // elapsed time in ms
    double elapsed_2 = 1000 * elapsed_data_2.count();

    printf("Elapsed time:\n1 => %g ms\n2 => %g ms\n", elapsed_1, elapsed_2);

    return 0;
}
```

With no nvcc optimization, I got the following results:

```
1 => 45.5977 ms
2 => 45.4554 ms
```

which indicates the same performance. Again, I am not sure if the conclusion here is generalizable and suspects it depends on your kernel and nvcc.